# Buttons not clickable in the upper half

Tags: android, xml, button, layout

The following buttons `display_current_month` and `display_current_year` in a `fragment` nested in coordinator layout are not clickable in the upper half.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/activity_custom_calendar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/display_current_month"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/display_current_year"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/display_current_month"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/calendar_days_of_week"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/display_current_month"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The coordinator layout :

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
android:id="@+id/reminders_app_bar_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/shape_rounded_rectangle">

<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:id="@+id/reminders_collapsing_toolbar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/calendar_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="380dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Attached screenshot with actual buttons. Any help is much appreciated.

P.S. The buttons seem to have a bottom padding, which allows the buttons to be clicked with ~ 10 dp below their border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your view pager is located under your toolbar, that's why you can't click on your buttons and your toolbar will get your screen's touchs.
you can put below code inside your ViewPager tag in your xml.

```
android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
```

Comment: How to also fix the clickable area on the lower part of the buttons ? The buttons seem to have a padding(clickable area) below them, outside their border.

Comment: i couldn't see the extra clickable's area, please show me more details, maybe it's because of your test's device, change your environment and tell me the result.

Answer (score 0):

By default buttons are clickable and should get click events callback in java file as well untill you are not setting clickListener dynamically to null.